# java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.setAccessible(boolean)" because "ao" is null

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am doing Dynamic Web Project using JPA in Java 17. I have a class called UserEntity. In the first page I have a register button, which has the following functionality:

```
private void register(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        String password = request.getParameter("register-pass");
        String repeatPassword = request.getParameter("confirm-register-pass");
        if (!password.equals(repeatPassword)) {
            request.setAttribute("error", "Password mismatch!");
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("error.jsp");
            try {
                dispatcher.forward(request, response);
            } catch (ServletException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            JPAUserRepository repo = new JPAUserRepository();
            String username = request.getParameter("register-user");
            String email = request.getParameter("register-email");
            UserEntity user = new UserEntity(username, password, email);
            
            if(repo.registerUser(user)) {
                HttpSession session = request.getSession();
                session.setAttribute("user", user);
                
                try {
                    response.sendRedirect("profile.jsp");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }else {
            }
        }
    }
```

The registerUser function from the repository is:

```
public boolean registerUser(UserEntity user) {
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        try {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(user);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (TransactionalException e) {
            em.getTransaction().rollback();
            return false;
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

This is my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="MetaVerse" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>
            org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider
        </provider>
        <class>uni.fmi.masters.entities.UserEntity</class>
        <class>uni.fmi.masters.entities.CommentEntity</class>
        
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.h2.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:h2:~/MetaVerseDB"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.user" value="sa"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.flushMode" value="FLUSH_AUTO"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        </properties>
    
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

When I click on register, NullPointerException error occurs. I have added to the build path javassist-3.27.0-GA-javadoc.jar, but the issue is still not resolved. **How can I solve this problem?**

```
Root Cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.setAccessible(boolean)" because "ao" is null
    javassist.util.proxy.SecurityActions.setAccessible(SecurityActions.java:103)
    javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass3(DefineClassHelper.java:151)
    javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass2(DefineClassHelper.java:134)
    javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass(DefineClassHelper.java:95)
    javassist.util.proxy.FactoryHelper.toClass(FactoryHelper.java:131)
    javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass3(ProxyFactory.java:530)
    javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass2(ProxyFactory.java:515)
    javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass1(ProxyFactory.java:451)
    javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass(ProxyFactory.java:422)
    org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory.postInstantiate(JavassistProxyFactory.java:75)
    org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:162)
    org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:156)
    org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:58)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:88)
    org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:116)
    org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:382)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:519)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:124)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:96)
    org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77)
    org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(MetamodelImpl.java:129)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:300)
    org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462)
    org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892)
    org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
    javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    uni.fmi.masters.repositories.JPAUserRepository.getEntityManager(JPAUserRepository.java:47)
    uni.fmi.masters.repositories.JPAUserRepository.registerUser(JPAUserRepository.java:16)
    uni.fmi.masters.HelloWorldServlet.register(HelloWorldServlet.java:128)
    uni.fmi.masters.HelloWorldServlet.doPost(HelloWorldServlet.java:68)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there are multiple things that can cause this

- Your Java POJO Mapping class may not have the empty/default constructor
- Any collections you have should have the default constructor or overridden hashcode and equals method. That is, the same rules apply for any joined collections/parent-children.

If you have your constructors right for POJO classes than check hibernate.properties file and try changing

```
hibernate.bytecode.provider=javassist
```

to

```
hibernate.bytecode.provider=bytebuddy
```

Answer (score 2):

To those who stumble on this question looking for a clue. I had this issue on my staging environment in Google Cloud Platform but not while running locally. I solved it by updating the version of `org.hibernate:hibernate-gradle-plugin` and `org.hibernate:hibernate-c3p0` from `5.2.9.Final` to `5.6.1.Final`. Magic.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the existing javaasisst, installed it again and now it works with the newest version.

Comment: So my answer was correct? if so please approve it

Comment: If that's the case then this post isn't helpful for the community so feel free to delete it